# Click event object tracking woes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am working on this but of jQuery that gets the element id through a click event. This then triggers a function that acts like the deprecated .toggle()- it slides an element down on the fist click and slides that element up on the second click. However, there is a bug that causes the element to slide up and down the amount of times that it has been clicked on. For instance, if this is the second time I use the .clickToggle function, the element (table) slides up and down twice before settling, and so on. I suspect it has something to do with the event object, e, tracking the number of clicks-- i.e. I probably shouldn't set id = e.target.id-- but I'm not sure how to fix while still getting the relevant element id that I need.

Here is the relevant clickToggle plug in (courtesy of an answer here on stackoverflow).

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
            var funcs = [func1, func2];
            this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
            this.click(function() {
                var data = $(this).data();
                var tc = data.toggleclicked;
                $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
                data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
            });
            return this;
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

Here is the buggy code that fits the above description.

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
        //get the mouse info, and parse out the relevant generated div num 
        var id =  e.target.id; 
        var strId = id.match(/\d$/); 

        //clickToggle the individual table
        $('#showTable' + strId).clickToggle(function () {
            $('#table' + strId).slideDown();
            $('#table' + strId).load('files.php');      
        },
        function () {
            $('#table' + strId).slideUp();
        }); 
    });//close mousemove function
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're registering a new `click` handler for the element each time you invoke `clickToggle`:

```
this.click(function() {...
```

On each subsequent click, you add another handler, as well as invoking all previous handlers. Bleagh.

Better to be straightforward: **[(DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/9J22d/)**

```
var showTable = function($table) {
    $table.slideDown();
    $table.load('files.php');
    $table.removeClass('hidden');
};

var hideTable = function($table) {
    $table.slideUp();
    $table.addClass('hidden');
};

$(document).click(function (e) {
    //get the mouse info, and parse out the relevant generated div num 
    var id = e.target.id;
    var strId = id.match(/\d$/)[0];
    var $table = $('#table' + strId);

    if ($table.hasClass('hidden')) {
        showTable($table);
    } else {
        hideTable($table);
    }
});
```